# Django - Get parent object with children's object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django so I might miss the answer for this one because of terminology.

I am trying to get parent object with children objects, I've got:

```
#models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)


#serializer.py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

#views.py
Product.objects.all().filter(sub_category__category_id=category_id).select_related()
products_serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)

    return Response({
        'data': products_serializer.data
    })
```

I am trying to get parent **category** object within the children objects I've already got.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: add `models.py` file

Comment: Added @AstikAnand

Comment: Where is the Product Model definition ?

Answer (score 0):

You already have your parent object, you can access it through each of your objects:

```
products = Product.objects.all().filter(sub_category__category_id=category_id)
for product in products:
  parent = product.parent  # You already have it
```

For better performance change your query to

```
Product.objects.all().filter(sub_category__category_id=category_id).select_related('parent')
```

As commented you can do it through serializers:

```
class ProductItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductItem

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_items = ProductItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

Now just get categories and products and items will be nested

Comment: You can access the entire parent row, you can a foreignkey field in your child entity, that will be filled with parent object not just id

Comment: Thanks for your comment @serjik but I am trying to get the entire parent row:

category_id=category_id

Comment: It is may sound a little bit unclear but; I am trying to get the common parent object with all his related children's

I've made the code sample a little bit more detailed if that helps :)